# Add a "Facebook Login" to SimpleAuth's Instagram Login Page

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, instagram, ember-simple-auth

Is there anyway to add a **Facebook Login** to `SimpleAuth`'s Instagram Login Page?

I'm very surprised to have not found questions and/or tutorials about this, as quite a few Instagram Users have chose to **Login with Facebook** and cannot recall their **Instagram Login** credentials, but I am hoping that someone could shed some insight into whether it is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing Instagram's API requires OAuth 2.0. To answer my own question, **there is no way to login to Instagram using Facebook credentials** and you **CANNOT** alter the Web Browser login that SimpleAuth and Instagram provide.